my "lon" coordinate doesn't show up in a Geomap of Grafana
I have a problem with the geomap visualisation in grafana.
My data is stored in influxdb, It is stored as seen in this screenshot :
data query (lon and lat are float)
My problem is when I try to display it as geomap in Grafana : It only works if I fill lat and lon with the field "latitude", as if "longitude" was not recognised...
With lat and lat, it works (but it's not the good location! but
With lat and lon, problem
yet both fields are float...
I use Grafana v10.4.2 (22809dea50)
I tried to modify each configuration field to see if there is a bug somewhere. I tried the "auto" mode to get coordinates, the manual mode, modify the aliases... I also did a "math(/100)" to be very sure that "lon" is recognised as a float, and it's ok for this !
I except the "lon" to be recognised !

Please don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

When you tick "Table view" on top of the panel in edit mode, do you see expected values?

@markalex Yes I can see all the data.
Apparently it's not about the "longitude", but more about the 2 fields I have in my SELECT request.
If I remove my first field, the last one is considered. If I have 2 fields, the last one is not displayed. It depend if I select longitude or Latitude first actually.
I updated to v11.1, but my problem is still here. Am I missing something ?

I managed to find a solution.
In my opinon it is a bug of Grafana, that doesn’t take in account multiple “timeseries” fields in the request. It takes only the first field.
Here is the solution : in the request, format data as Table, not as timeseries…

